# Project creation based on custom archetype leaves out folders

Tags: maven, archetypes

I created my own maven archetype in my company's maven nexus.

The archetype jar file has all the necessary folders and pom.xml in the archetype-resources folder

But when I create a project based off of the archetype, the folders all get left out and only the pom.xml remains.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks

---

Just as a note, I tried to create the archetype jar in several ways:

```
mvn archetype:create-from-project
mvn install
mvn deploy
mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

I still get the same issue

Comment: I recommend showing more details in your question, such as the full project structure (the files) for the archetype project, its full pom.xml file, and the results you get on the file system when you try to create a new project from that archetype.

Comment: *At this point one can only specify individual files to be created but not empty directories.* - https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html.